# Find the lowest degree of the polynom $P$?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I have to determine the lowest degree of $P$ given by the following system :
$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
  P \equiv 2X \ \mod[X^2 -2X +1] \\
  P \equiv 3X \ \mod[X^2 -4X+4]
\end{array}
\right.$

First, I say that $\exists \ Q_1, Q_2 \in K[X]$ such as :

$P(X)=(X^2-2X+1)Q_1(X)+2X$ and $P(X)=(X^2-4X+4)Q_2(X)+3X$

Then I obtain : $(X^2-2X+1)Q_1(X)-(X^2-4X+4)Q_2(X)=-X$

Then I proved by euclidian divison that: $\gcd(X^2-2X+1,X^2-4X+4)=1$

So according to Bezout theorem, $\exists \ U, V \in K[X]$ such as :

$(X^2-2X+1)U(X)+(X^2-4X+4)V(X)=1$

I've tried to find a particular solution for $U,V$ and to solve it like a diophantine equation but I think it does not work for polynoms.
By intuition I said that $U(X)=aX+b$ and $V(X)=cX+d$ and found $U(X)=-2X+5$, $V(X)=2X-1$

Now I meet difficulties to find $P$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two polynomials you're reducing w.r.t. are perfect squares. Also, try the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: If you have run the Euclidean Algorithm to find the gcd, you can calculate "backwards" to find $U(X)$ and $V(X)$, in the same way as you may have done it earlier with integers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I tried this method and I found $U(X)=-2X+5$ and $V(X)=2X-1$ which was my particular solution. I got it by identification and by taking $U,V$ in the form $aX+b$.

Comment: If you can find $U_1(X), V_1(X)$ that give you $1/4$, you can multiply them by $4$ to obtain $1$ as a linear combination.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did what you said and found these polynoms but the final $P$ is not correct.

Comment: You were asking about $U$ and $V$. They can be a part of a strategy for finding $P$ using the same idea as in the proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Or else you can "guess" at the shape as suggested by Michael, and calculate. Your method based on subtraction need not work, having the difference be $-X$ does not guarantee that we have congruence to $2X$ and $3X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,a=x\!-\!1, b=x\!-\!2.\,$ Squaring a Bezout Identity (BI) for $\,\color{#c00}{a,b}\,$ yields a BI for $\,\color{#0a0}{a^2,b^2}$

$$1 = \color{#c00}{a-b}\overset{\rm square}\Rightarrow 1 = a^2\!+b^2\!-2ab(\color{#c00}{a\!-\!b})\ =\, (1\!-\!2b)\,\color{#0a0}{a^2}\!+(1\!+\!2a)\,\color{#0a0}{b^2}\qquad $$

Finally, from the BI  for $\,\color{#0a0}{a^2,b^2}$ we can read off the CRT solution in [the usual way,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/782295/242) $ $ i.e.

$\quad$ if $\ u \color{#0a0}{a^2}\! + v\color{#0a0}{b^2} = 1\ $ then $\ P = d ua^2\! + cvb^2\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\, P\equiv c\pmod{\!a^2},\ P\equiv d\pmod{\!b^2}$

Comment: You're right with your method I found the same $U$ and $V$, but now I don't know how to determine $P$

Comment: @Maman I added a remark on that.

Comment: $c$ and $d$ are polynoms ?

Comment: Then we have to find $c$ and $d$ ?

Comment: @Maman Yes, $\,a,b,c,d\, =\, (x\!-\!1)^2,\,(x\!-\!2)^2,\, 2x,\, 3x\,$ in your case, and $\,u,v\,=\, 1\!-\!2b,\, 1\!+\!2a\,=\, 5\!-\!2x,\, 2x\!-\!1.\ \ $

Comment: You are given $\,c,d,\,$ i.e. they are the RHS of the CRT system, $\,P\equiv c\pmod{a^2},\ P\equiv d\pmod{b^2}\ \ $

Comment: I found $P=-2x^4+29x^3-76x^2+58x$ it does not work

Comment: @Maman Right, that is not correct. Check your arithmetic.

Comment: @Maman The cofactors of $\,(x-1)^2\,$ and $\,(x-2)^2\,$ are wrong. Swap them to fix it, i.e. $\,dua^2 = (3x)(5-2x)(x-1)^2$

Comment: Thanks it works !!! But now how do we know that this is the lowest degree ?

Comment: Reduce it mod $\,F = (x-1)^2(x-2)^2\,$ to get a solution $P$ of degree $< \deg F.\,$ Such a solution is unique by CRT. Or, directly:  if $\,P'$ were another solution of deg $\le 3\,$ then $\,P\equiv P'\,$ mod $\,(x\!-\!1)^2$ and mod $(x\!-\!2)^2$ so also mod their lcm = product $= F$. Then $\,F\mid P-P',\,$ so $\,P-P' = 0$ since it has smaller degree than $F$ (this is the proof of the *uniqueness* (mod $F)$ of the CRT solution).

Comment: Ok so we apply CRT to solve this kind of problems. Interesting.

Comment: @Maman Yes, just as for integers, polynomials (over a field) enjoy a Division with Remainder algorithm, so they enjoy a Euclidean algorithm, Bezout identity, etc. A conveneient way to do the Extended Euclidean algorithm (to get $U,V)$ is in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Comment: Ok thanks, is it possible to find another $P$ with $\deg(P)=4$ ?

Comment: @Maman If $P$ is a solution then $P'$ is a solution $\iff P'\equiv P\pmod F.\,$ Therefore the complete set of solutions is $\ P + Q F\,$ for all polynomials $Q.\,$ This implies that there exists a solution of degree $\,d\iff d\ge 3.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

You could say that $P(1)=2$, $P'(1)=2$, $P(2)=6$, $P'(2)=3$.  This is four equations in the coefficients of $P(x)$.  Let $P(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$, and you have four equations in four coefficients.  For example, $P(1)=A+B+C+D=2$.