# Give an example of a ring in which there exist $x,y,z \in R\setminus\{1,0\}$ such that $x$ is a unit, $y$ is nilpotent, and $z$ is idempotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Give an example of a ring in which there exist $x,y,z \in R\setminus\{1,0\}$ such that $x$ is a unit, $y$ is nilpotent, and $z$ is idempotent.

I have an idea of the form $R = \mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$.
I just need to justify my answer. I have a feeling $n$ is a prime number. How can I justify this?

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then $R$ is a field and so there are no non-zero nilpotents, and no idempotents other than $0$ or $1$. So if there for an example of this form, $n$ is necessarily *not* prime.

Comment: thanks for the edit, any suggestions on how to find such an example?

Comment: Do your rings have to be commutative? If not, then $2\times2$ matrices over a field will do.

Comment: yes we have been working with commutative rings only

Comment: for it to be a unit such that there exists y $\in$ R that xy=yx=1, can x = y?
 For example, i think R = $Z$/12$Z$ where the unit may be [5][5] =1 . It works that [6] is nilpotent and [3] is idempotent.

Comment: Brandon - I think you have the right idea, but $3^2=9$ is not idempotent according to the definition I know.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, $x$ can be equal to $y$. (The definition doesn't say anything to rule this out.) But Mark is right, $3$ is not idempotent in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,n\,$ is composite and not a prime power then $\,\Bbb Z/n\,$ has an idempotent $\not\equiv 1,0\,$ since then $\,n = ab,\,$ coprime $\,a,b>1$ so by CRT $\ \exists\,x\equiv (1,0)\ {\rm mod}\ (a,b)\,$ so $\,x^2\equiv (1,0)^2\equiv (1^2,0^2)\equiv x.\,$

Further if $\,n\,$ is not squarefree then a prime power $\,p^2\mid n\,$ so $\,{\rm mod}\ n\!:\ n/p\not\equiv 0,\,$ but $\, (n/p)^2\equiv 0$

Finally, $ $ if $\,n> 2\,$ then $\ {-1}\not\equiv 1,0,\ $ so $\ {-}1\,$ is a nontrivial unit.

**Example** $\ $ Simple cases arise for $\, n = p^2q,\,$ primes $\,p\ne q, \,$ e.g. $\ 2^2\cdot 3 = 12.\,$ Then, as above we have an idempotent $\,x\equiv (1,0)\ {\rm mod}\ (3,4)\!\!\overset{\rm CRT}\iff\! x\equiv 4\pmod{12},\,$ indeed $\,4^2\equiv 4\pmod{12}.$

Further we have the nonzero nilpotent $\,n/p = pq\,$ with $\,n^2\! = p^2q^2 \equiv 0\pmod {p^2q}.\,$ In our example $\, n/p =  12/2 = 6,\,$ and $\,6^2\equiv 0\pmod{12}.$

**Remark** $\,\ \color{#c00}{\rm Nontrivial\,}$ idempotents, i.e. elements satisfying $\,x^2 = x\,$ (and $\,\color{#c00}{x\neq 0,1})$ are [intimately connected to coprime factorizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614256/242) (of both elements and rings). As was explained above, by CRT, modulo any non-prime-power composite $\,n,\,$ there are nontrivial idempotents $\,(0,1),(1,0).$

Some integer factorization algorithms work by searching for nontrivial idempotents mod $\,n,\,$ which immediately yield a factorization of $\,n\,$ ([generally one can quickly factor $\,n\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) given any polynomial which has more roots mod $\,n\,$ than its degree, so any notrivial idempotent or nontrivial square-root will split $\,n,\,$ since it yields a quadratic with $\,\color{#c00}3\,$ roots).