# Relationship when some number divided by two different (relatively prime) divisors results in the same remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

This is a clarification from Rosen's discrete mathematics book. It says that 'by the Chinese Remainder theorem' the following is true:
if $x\equiv y \mod{p}$ and $x\equiv y \mod{q}$, then if p and q are relatively prime: $x\equiv y \mod{pq}$.

I know the Chinese Remainder theorem allows us to multiply relatively prime moduli together as long as we create a solution x in a certain form, but I don't see how this conclusion would follow.

I thought of doing it this way (may be wrong):

$x\equiv y \mod{q}$ is the same as $x-y\equiv 0 \mod{q}$

$x\equiv y \mod{p}$ is the same as $x-y\equiv 0 \mod{p}$

So we can write these equations as $x-y = k_1p = k_2q$ for some integers $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Then I multiply the equations to get $(x-y)^2 = k_1k_2pq$, and converting back to a congruence: $(x-y)^2\equiv 0 \mod{pq}$.

And then we can reduce it down to $(x-y)\equiv 0 \mod{pq}$ which is $x\equiv y \mod{pq}$

I am unsure if the above is a correct way to get to this conclusion, but even if it is correct I don't see how the chinese remainder theorem plays a role.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the *uniqueness* of the CRT solution: $\,x\equiv y\pmod{pq}\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv y $ mod $p$ and mod $q$ so it is a solution, and by CRT the solution is unique $\!\pmod{pq}$.

But there is no need to use CRT since $\,p,q\mid x-y\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(p,q)=pq\mid x-y,\,$ by $\gcd(p,q)=1.\ $ This is exactly how CRT uniqueness is usually proved, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614256/242)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. One last thing, is the way that I did it considered valid? Or did I make some leaps in my logic?

Comment: @Slade To complete your proof you need to justify the inference $\,pq\mid (x-y)^2\,\Rightarrow\, pq\mid x-y.\ \ $

Comment: Is it enough to convert to a congruence $(x-y)^2\equiv 0\bmod{pq}$, and since we can multiply congruences, and we know that the only number multiplied by itself to result in 0 is 0, then $(x-y)\equiv 0\bmod{pq}$ as well?

Comment: @Slade No, since e.g. mod $4$ we have $2^2\equiv 0,$ but $2\not\equiv 0.\ $ It is true for squarefree moduli that $\,a^2\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv 0\,$ but this requires proof.

Comment: Okay, understood! Thanks!